# Pages views limit

Tags: pages, limit

Is there a option or plugin that can limit a number of pages user can view per month? Im trying to make a site with video and text toturials and I need to limit user to view only 10 lessons (pages with video or text conent) per subscrition period (1 month) or something like user credit system that give users 10 cretits monthly user can than spend 1 credit per lesson?

Thanks